# Preserving double and single quotes and escape characters when inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, double, quotes

I have a problem when inserting into mysql.

I have a multidimensional array in javascript that gets converted into a string in JSON format.
The string looks like this for example:

`[["text1","text2","te'xt with apostroph'e"],["subarray2","a \u000a unicode number","change line \n \n"]]`

So the thing is that this format uses double quotes outside the fields, and then inside sometimes I have single quotes, and escape characters `\` as you can see.

If I send this from javascript to php through ajax and decode it in php, it all works great, no problems, perfect.

The problem comes when I need to insert it into mysql.

1. magic_quotes is off everywhere in php.ini
2. I do use mysql_real_escape_string function before I insert in mysql

But whatever I do, the insert is successful, but in the database the double quotes get converted to single quotes, and also the `\` escape characters disappear.

So inside database I am left with this:

`[['text1','text2','te'xt with apostroph'e'],['subarray2','a u000a unicode number','change line n n']]`

This is a problem of course as I need to preserve the double quotes so that when I read this from php later, I can decode the JSON and still keep the single quotes inside the text.  Also the `\n` new line and the `\u000a` unicode characters dont work anymore because the escape characters have disappeared.

I found the trick to use `htmlspecialchars($thephrase, ENT_QUOTES);`
which converts double quotes to `&quot`. This at least preserves my double quotes and single quotes separated, but this is obviously not the ideal solution, plus I still lose the escape `\` characters.

Something is obviously wrong in what I'm doing or the configuration, the problem is not related to the JSON, if I simply insert directly in mysql double and single quotes together, the double ones get converted to single.

So anyway the question I guess is, in a text where I have double quotes, single quotes, escape characters and new line characters, how can I make sure that, when I insert all that in mysql, I preserve all of those in the mysql varchar or text field; double quotes, single quotes, `\` escape characters and new line characters?

I have made sure that magic_quotes is off everywhere in php.ini

Thank you very much for any advice or help.

Comment: Try using PDO (http://www.php.net/pdo) instead; so much easier and more reliable using the ancient mysql library and doing all the work yourself with mysql_real_escape_string...

Comment: very interesting, thank you for your advice, i will research and try to use PDO in next projects, but for this project i cant change the whole code , there should be a way to fix it hopefully without the pdo , thing is, preserving double quotes and escape characters when inserting into mysql should be easy to accomplish:) something im doing wrong for sure :)thank u again :)

Answer (score 1):

By now you should have solved your issue. For future reference, I think what you were looking for was php's [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or the more specific [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). These functions will escape the characters that need to be quoted in database queries.

On a side note, I'd recommend you write your questions as succinct as possible. People tend to skip over huge testaments.